# Skrollr.js Plugin Not Parallaxing Inside Bootstrap Carousel - Fiddle Provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, skrollr

I am having a problem with the SKrollr.js plugin for Parallax and smooth scrolling. Everything works fine except Bootstrap carousel's, and im sure any carousel for that matter. It's clearly a display:none problem when the plugin is setting itself up on load and can't see any of the .item classes. But I can't figure out how on earth to get Skrollr to see all of the slides/.item classes when it's rendering.

I even tried this kinda stuff. My Skrollr markup isn't the problem that code always works for me.

**Skrollr Markup**

```
data-10p-top-bottom="background-position-y: 100%;" data-bottom-top="background-position-y: 0%;"
```

**CSS**

```
.displaying {
    display: block !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
var sk = skrollr.init({
    forceHeight: false,
    beforerender: function(data) {
        $(".item").addClass('displaying');
    },
    render: function(data) {
        $(".item").removeClass('displaying');
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I made a JSFiddle for it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/goredefex/42udd28g/) or you can see it fullscreen for debugging [here](https://jsfiddle.net/goredefex/42udd28g/embedded/result/)

Sorry I was being vague and general because I know my HTML is solid. Check the fiddle. The slider functions just fine it's Skrollr not being able to see the hidden slides at runtime that is the problem. I just need a better solution to solve this.

Comment: Could you please post where you have these `.item` classes in your code?

Comment: done and added fiddle to see what I mean

Comment: I see skrollr is working on all 3 slides, just subtly.  What is the desired functionality?

Comment: Really??? What browser? In chrome for me only the first one is parallaxed the other two are static. Did you check in inspector and look at its background-y position? Or just eye balled it. The link I gave that shows only the compiled output on a stand alone page might be easier to judge it.

Comment: I'm in Chrome, I can see the background-position-y changing

Comment: Here's the twist, I only see it parallaxing if the browser is resized.  So you may be having a refresh issue with skrollr.  Just posted a possible solution, give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you need to do a refresh since I notice it works if I resize the browser.

Try this code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
skrollr.get().refresh();
}, 0);
```

You can change the timeout to 1000 if necessary to ensure everything loads.

Comment: Had to crank the timer up to 3000 (his power level... 3000!!) but yeah worked like a charm thanks :) . My name is also Christian so if I could give you 10 more points I would.

Comment: Also, for anyone landing here off of Google. I tried doing a simple refresh prior to posting, but clearly the DOM needed more time to load. Timeout was needed.

Comment: Haha, people named Christian Unite.