# Skrollr.js Plugin Background Position Y Not Parallaxing

Tags: css, firefox, parallax, skrollr, background-position

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869564/skrollr-js-plugin-not-parallaxing-inside-bootstrap-carousel-fiddle-provided).

I am using Skrollr.js for parallax, which I have created a simple fiddle to show my markup and js. The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/goredefex/42udd28g/2/) and the full page result is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/goredefex/42udd28g/2/embedded/result/).

I cannot figure out why I can all of the background images parallaxing on Chrome and Safari but when it comes to Firefox, no luck. Can anyone help me understand why these fiddles don't work but [this](https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/) does work, which uses the same code.

Is it that...

```
background-position-y: 100%;
```

Doesn't animate in Firefox or something? If not then why does the demo that I linked work no trouble?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is a problem with Firefox and background-position-y.  You just need to modify your code to so that it has the x and y value.  Something like:

```
background-position: 0% 100%;
```

Where 0% is the x value and 100% is the y value.